# What permissions are needed to read the Azure AD users' calendar via Graph API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to access the calendars of Azure AD users. I do it with the code below:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var tenantId = "MY_TENANT_ID";
var clientId = "APP_ID";
var clientSecret = "APP_SECRET";


var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var user = await graphClient.Users["USER_ID"]
    .Calendar.Events
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
Status Code: Unauthorized

Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: NoPermissionsInAccessToken

Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.
```

In **Azure AD->App Registrations->API permissions** I have got **Calendars.Read** permission, but don't have **User.Read.All** permission. So the question is can I get data from calendars without **User.Read.All** permission and if I can what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this set up as an application permission or a delegated permission.  If application permission then you need admin consent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), you used client credential flow to obtain the authentication and call graph api to [list all calendar events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) for a specific user.

So you need to make your azure ad application to get `Calendar.Read application` permission. Without the permission then you can't call the api successfully

[image]

How to add application permission:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! I've got a delegated calendar permission but not the application permission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I'm glad to see it work for you : )